# How can I negate an anti-tech field magic spell?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

I am currently playing a campaign as a gunslinger, and all was going well, we even found some guns, but then we encountered an enemy group with a spell called [anti-tech field](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/antitech-field/) and so I, a gunslinger whose bullets are useless against such an enemy, am trying to find some other solution. I have a feeling this will come up again. Basically, I'm trying to disable a magic shield without getting too close to it. Maybe some kind of magic. Also no 3rd party spells the DM doesn't like them.

Comment: What sort of level PC group are we talking about? (As Antitech is reasonably high level). What resources do you have? Can you rely on other player's characters to help?

Comment: @YogoZuno. we're all level 7-8. I can rely on the others and we have a decent amount of stuff but I'm saving up for something. I have a friend who is multiclassing as a sorcerer rogue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## You can’t.

The only things that can remove an *anti-tech field* are high-level dispel effects. As a 5th- or 6th-level spell, *greater dispel magic* is probably a minimum.

You don’t get that as a gunslinger. In fact, you get absolutely nothing that is at all helpful. Your only hope is to have a spellcaster ally use dispels. You can’t even use a magic item, because dispelling is heavily dependent on caster level and that just costs too much in magic-item form, and magic items capable of casting a spell as high-level as *greater dispel magic* are rare in the extreme anyway: it’s too high-level for a wand, so you need a staff. None of the printed staffs have it—the *staff of abjuration* has *dispel magic* but your odds of success with a +10 cap on the dispel check are poor indeed. So you need a custom staff. And since you have no caster level of your own, it has to be a staff with a high caster level. That costs immensely, and assumes you can hit the DC 20 Use Magic Device check.

So there is just no way for you to respond.

Which is why *anti-tech field* is a completely unreasonable spell: for one spell, a spellcaster can shut down your entire class. If enemies have that effect, you are effectively a commoner, shut out of contributing to combat—and since gunslinger is a combat class, that means you are basically unable to play the character you chose to play.

Compare to *antimagic field*—itself a terrible design that really should not be part of the game. *Antimagic field* is at least as bad for the caster as it is for anyone else, while *anti-tech field* does absolutely nothing to your average druid. Moreover, spellcasters **can** overcome *antimagic field*, with Conjuration (creation), SR: No spells, or with buffs on allies with ranged or reach attacks, or by summoning some allies with ranged or reach attacks. And all these difficulties are applied to spellcasters—by far the most powerful classes in Pathfinder. The gunslinger, in contrast, is a mediocre class good at only one thing—and that thing is completely negated by *anti-tech field*.

So where a spellcaster can only be partially shut down by *antimagic field*, and that spell requires the enemy to also shut themselves down, and spellcasters are immensely powerful, *anti-tech field* shuts you down entirely, does absolutely nothing to most casters, and you are a class that is already struggling. As bad as *antimagic field* is for the game, *anti-tech field* is orders of magnitude worse. Frankly, there isn’t much use for it *other than* hosing gunslingers and similar.

And that is, quite simply, bad GMing. If it was one enemy among a group and it took teamwork and coordination to get things to work, that’d be one thing. But if this is really appearing commonly and everyone has this defense, your GM is screwing you over. If they don’t realize that, I have to question how well they know this system and whether or not they’re qualified to run a game. And if they do realize that, then they’re a pretty awful GM for thinking this is appropriate.

So I would try, maybe, talking to the GM. Point out how this spell is unreasonably asymmetric, should never have been printed, and is shutting you out of the game. Maybe you can convince them to stop using it, or use it sparingly/in a way that presents a challenge without totally shutting you out. And if they refuse, you have to choose between playing in this game as a second-class citizen, or finding a new game.

That’s it. There is just *nothing* you can do pro-actively about this, and that’s terrible. Paizo should never have printed this spell for that reason, and no GM should use it for that reason. It just leaves you with only bad options: beg the GM to stop, accept being sidelined from much of the game, or leave. That is what Paizo has pushed you to by publishing this spell. I hope you’re as angry about that as I am.

I mean, *how on earth is a flying piece of lead “tech” in the first place?*

Comment: Oh, well, there's a thing one can do to avoid being shut out of the game. It's _not playing a gunslinger in the first place_. I never said it was a nice and fair option, did I?

Comment: we've found a solution. the guys that cast this have extremely low CON and so my vampire buddy and I can just drain them to kill them. this works partially because the only guys with the spell are guarded by robots that take 5 turns to aim.

Comment: As much as the overall logic of your answer is accurate...there ARE things the gunslinger can do, despite them being fairly suboptimal, like using a bow or crossbow, or even a melee weapon. Or running away.

Comment: @YogoZuno They are no longer a gunslinger if they do those things. Nothing about the character they choose to play applies if they do that. And Pathfinder punishes you mercilessly for doing things outside your specialty, to the point that you might as well not bother.

Comment: @KRyan Not true at all...gunslingers still have full BAB, and high hit die. They even have a deed that supports making melee attacks (pistolwhip). Given the comparitive price of ammunition at low levels, and the problems of underwater combat, there are plenty of other circumstances where guns just don't work as well. Much like any character, you have to plan for times when you can't use your main schtick.

Comment: @YogoZuno Most of us don’t enjoy playing an NPC in a party of PCs.

Comment: @YogoZuno the reason why I wanted to use my guns instead of a melee weapon is because I can do tons of damage with the guns combined with my +7 dex and feats.